# Inexpressibility results for first-order logic that fail extending the language

Tags: first-order-logic

Think of the classical inexpressivity results that one studies in early courses about first-order logic, *e.g.* that on a signature with a binary predicate $R$ one cannot express that $R$ is connected. Or, that one cannot express $R$-reachability between two points $x$ and $y$.

Now I'm wondering what happens if I extend the language. Does any such property become expressible? For example, in a signature with $R$ and *something else*, can I express connectivity of $R$?

Are there examples of properties not FO-expressible in a signature but expressible in an extended signature?

I'm not considering here extending the theory as well. So if you have $>$ and extend the signature with an interpreted $+$, that's not what I'm looking for.

**Edit**: I'll add an example that I've found after posting the question.

Take the signature $\Sigma$ with a binary predicate $R$ and two constants $s$ and $d$. Let $X$ be the property of $d$ being *not* $R$-reachable from $s$. $X$ is not expressible in FO. But if I consider $\Sigma'$ which adds a unary predicate $P$, I can write:

$$
  \psi\equiv P(s) \land \forall xy ((P(x) \land R(x,y)) \to P(y)) \land \neg P(d)
$$

Is it correct that a structure $\mathcal{M}$ has property $X$ iff $\psi$ is satisfied in *some* expansion of $\mathcal{M}$? This extension would be the one where $P$ is interpreted as the fixpoint of $R$.

Is all of this correct?

Comment: The question is ambiguous as to what expansions of the original models you consider. E.g., *any* property becomes expressible if you expand the signature with a nullary predicate that is true in a given model iff the original property holds.

Comment: But if you want a sentence that expresses the property in *exery* expansion of the original model to the new signature, then this is equivalent to first-order expressivity, as you can always define some such expansion in the original model itself (e.g., make all new predicates empty).

Comment: What does it mean to extend the signature, but not the theory? If you add a new symbol $\phi$ but no axioms for it, you won't be able to do much with $\phi$.

Comment: I don’t think the formula $\psi$ in the edit does what you think it does, as it is logically equivalent to $\forall x\,P(x)\land\forall x\,\forall y\,R(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, that was wrong. I should have looked for expressing *non*-reachability, and the "iff" was wrong. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments it takes some care to phrase this question in a nontrivial way. However, this can be done in at least a couple ways, one yielding a positive answer and the other yielding a negative answer.

---

As clarified in your edit, you have in mind the following question: is there a non-first-order property $X$ of structures which is *existentially second-order* (= $\Sigma^1_1$ or $\mathsf{ESO}$) characterizable? Here $\mathsf{ESO}$ is the logic which allows expressions of the form "Some expansion of the universe satisfies $\varphi$" for $\varphi\in\mathsf{FOL}$. Note that $\mathsf{ESO}$ is quite a nice logic in many respects - e.g. it is fully compact and has downward Lowenheim-Skolem - but it is not closed under negation (so we don't contradict [Lindstrom's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem), and in fact [Shelah/Vaananen](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01145) showed that there is no direct analogue of Lindstrom's theorem for logics without negation). Broadly speaking, a good rule of thumb is that existential second-order logic is "tame" in a way that its dual (universal second-order logic) isn't; for example, the latter but not the former can characterize well-foundedness, which turns out to be a very strong anti-tameness property.

The answer to this question is **yes**. There is a vast literature on the topic, and the term "existential second-order" will be a useful search term. One easy example is that a structure is infinite iff it can be expanded to a model of (say) Robinson's arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$ in a fresh signature. Note that this leans heavily on the lack of negation in $\mathsf{ESO}$: the reason infinitude is not $\mathsf{FOL}$-expressible is roughly that if it were then finiteness would also be $\mathsf{FOL}$-expressible and that would contradict compactness, but this relies on $\mathsf{FOL}$ having negation.

---

Interestingly, if we ask for the stronger property of both $X$ and $\neg X$ being "detectable" in this way (and this was how I originally interpreted your question), we get a **negative** answer.

Let $\Sigma$ be a fixed language and suppose $X$ is a property of $\Sigma$-structures of interest. Suppose $R_1, R_2$ are relation symbols not in $\Sigma$ and there are sentences $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ in $\Sigma\sqcup\{R_1\},\Sigma\sqcup\{R_2\}$ respectively which "detect $X$-ness" in the sense that for every $\Sigma$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ we have

- $\mathcal{M}$ has property $X$ iff **some** expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\varphi_1$, and
- $\mathcal{M}$ fails property $X$ iff **some** expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\varphi_2$.

In this case, the pair $\varphi_1\wedge\varphi_2$ is inconsistent (given a putative model of $\varphi_1\wedge\varphi_2$, does the reduct to $\Sigma$ satisfy $X$ or not?). This means $\vdash\varphi_1\rightarrow\neg\varphi_2$. Applying [Craig's interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation), we get a $\Sigma$-sentence $\theta$ entailed by $\varphi_1$ and entailing $\neg\varphi_2$. This $\theta$, then, exactly characterizes $X$.

---

At this point, it's worth seeing an example of a logic (necessarily not first-order logic $\mathsf{FOL}$) for which Craig interpolation *fails*. The two most common extensions of $\mathsf{FOL}$, namely the "small" infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ and second-order logic $\mathsf{SOL}$, each do have the interpolation property (interestingly and trivially, respectively), so we have to go into the weeds a bit.

My personal favorite example is $\mathsf{FOL}(Q_\mathit{fin})$, where we add to first-order logic the quantifier "For finitely many." The point is that $(i)$ **unlike** $\mathsf{FOL}$ this logic we can pin down the standard model of arithmetic $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ up to isomorphism, but $(ii)$ **like** $\mathsf{FOL}$ this logic can in $\mathcal{N}$ give an inductive definition of its own full theory of $\mathcal{N}$. These facts, combined with (the proof of) [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), give us the failure of Beth definability (a corollary of Craig interpolation) for $\mathsf{FOL}(Q_\mathit{fin})$.

Vaananen's article [*The Craig interpolation theorem in abstract model theory*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-008-9357-z) contains a lot of good information about this topic, albeit at a high level.

Comment: As noted in the comments, the question is unclear. But under the “for every expansion” reading that you seem to have adopted, you don’t need anything as heavy-handed as Craig’s interpolation (which fails for finite model theory, anyway); it follows trivially by interpreting $R$ as $\varnothing$, as also noted in the comments.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry, that was of course a typo. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks! My intended interpretation of the question was exactly this, that $\mathcal{M}$ has property $X$ iff some extension of $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\phi_1$. But in your argument above you seem to assume that there is also a formula for characterizing the failure to have the property ($\phi_2$), which I think is a stronger assumption, isn't it?

Comment: I've added an example that I think I've found after posting the question. Is it correct?

Comment: @gigabytes If you assume this interpretation, and do not require the same for complement, then the answer is simply that a property can be characterized like this if and only if it is $\Sigma^1_1$-definable (this is more or less just restating the definition). In the realm of of finite models, a property invariant under isomorphism  is $\Sigma^1_1$ iff it is in NP. An example of such a property that isn't FO-definable is non-connectedness.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of characterization I was looking for

Comment: @gigabytes I've edited my answer to align with your clarified question.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for! I don't know who downvoted it!

Answer (score 1):

First, a terminological note: an *extension* of a model is a model in the same signature obtained by adding elements into the domain. What you are talking about is called an *expansion* (new relations are added to the signature, but the domain and old relations are preserved).

A property can be characterized as stipulated in the question if and only if it is $\Sigma^1_1$-definable (i.e., expressible in existential second-order logic). This is pretty much just by definition.

In the realm of finite models, Fagin’s theorem states that a property is $\Sigma^1_1$-definable if and only if it is in NP and invariant under isomorphism.

As meanwhile added to the question, a simple example that’s not first-order definable is the property that $d$ is *not* reachable from $s$.

The property that $d$ *is* reachable from $s$ is also expressible in this way, as it is computable in NP (or indeed, NL). The following formula should work:

$$\begin{align*}
\forall x\,x\nless x&\land\forall x,y,x\,(x<y\land y<z\to x<z)\\
&\land\forall x,y\,(P(x,y)\leftrightarrow(x=s\lor\exists u,v\,(P(u,v)\land R(u,x)\land v<y)))\\
&\land\exists y\,P(d,y).
\end{align*}$$

This expresses the construction of the set of elements reachable from $s$ by induction along a partial order $<$ (which you can think of simply as a linear order, but it only matters for soundness that is well-founded).

Comment: Thanks! Also for the terminological clarification. I've changed extension to expansion in the question.